# Using the function of a specific library

Tags: c++, c

I have a problem: I would like to use the function `abs` of the library `complex`.

However, I undergo an error warning me the function `abs` used is `#define abs(x)  (x > 0) ? x : -(x)`.

Thus, I think the problem comes from my imports. Because of I also include the stdio and stdlib libraries, the compiler may use the function `abs` defined in one of these libraries.

So my question is: how can I use the function `abs` of the library `complex` without removing any import ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your response.

Comment: Does the library `complex` have a namespace?

Comment: Yes, the namespace is std. I use the libray "complex" of the standart C99

Comment: `std` is a C++ namespace.

Comment: @John: I think the macro is defined is the stdlib or stdio library and I would like to keep it working

Comment: Are you working in C or C++?  Where do you find that badly-defined `#define abs(x)` macro?  There are no 'imports' in C or C++; there are `#include` lines.  `<complex.h>` is a header in C99; it is not a library.  The `<complex.h>` header in C99 declares `cabs*()` functions, but not `abs()` — that is defined in `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: I'd look for the macro in windows.h, are you using this header? AFAICR it #defines quite a lot of things, including min and max

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wrap parens around it.

```
(abs)(whatever);
```

This will force the compiler to use the function version because the macro no longer matches.

Function-like macros work by matching an identifier followed by a left paren `(`. Since we've wrapped the function name itself in parens, we have instead an identifier followed by a right paren `)`, which fails to match the macro. The parens are semantically transparent, but they inhibit the macro syntax.

IIRC, it was `splint` the C checker which taught this to me. While writing a postscript interpreter, I created nice short macros to access the stack.

```
#define push(o) (*tos++ = (o))
#define pop() (*--tos)
```

Which were great until the tricky parts where they were part of an expression involving `tos`. To avoid undefined behavior, I had to create function versions and use those for those tricky spots. For the new design, I skipped the macros altogether.

---

Edit: I've got a nagging feeling that it was actually the Coelocanthe book (Peter Van Der Linden's *Deep C Secrets*) where I learned this, the above situation being where I first *needed* it. IIRC his example involved `putchar` or `getchar` which are often implemented as both functions and macros in conforming C implementations.

Comment: Fine ! It works. Can you explain me why the parentheses force the compiler to use the correct definition ?

Comment: A function-like macro invocation consists of a macro name followed by an open parenthesis.  When the compiler sees `abs)`, it cannot be an invocation of a function-like macro because the characters after the name is not an open parenthesis.

Answer (score 6):

Use `#undef`

```
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"
#undef abs // remove abs macro

x = std::abs(y);
```

Answer (score 4):

Whilst several suggestions above are very good, I would take a completely different angle. It is almost certainly something like `windows.h` that causes the "bad" macro definition of `abs()`. You should be able to NOT include "windows.h" in the file that does the complex math [in most types of programs, at least] (I'm not aware of a single function in Windows that takes `complex<T>` as an argument, so I'm pretty certain you don't need both "complex.h" and "windows.h" in the same source file. This method is called "isolating the system dependencies", and doing that is a very good thing.

Have a look at your code, and find where you are ACTUALLY using windows functions, and then only include "windows.h" in the files that actually need it. You'll probably find, if you are using Visual Studio, that "windows.h" is included as part of "stdafx.h", which means that all sort of interesting macros etc are being included all over the place, because "stdafx.h" is included in ALL source files.

Comment: +1, that `abs` macro must be avoided. It is the only real solution.

Answer (score 1):

Both `#undef` and parentheses solutions will work but I would advise to have something a little stronger, because both those solutions will required you to do them every time you want to call `abs` and next time you may forget and result in a bug.

what you can do:

1. change the name of your function to less common name : `absolute`, `myAbs` etc...
2. put you function\class under a name space (for C++ not for C) then the calls are explicit `myNameSpace::abs(x)`
3. If it won't work as the comment here suggested I would still warp the call in my function:

   type myAbs(type param)
   {
       return (abs)(param);
   }

Comment: A namespace won't defeat the macro substitution.

Comment: I'm not sure there is any "your function", at least OP doesn't mention that.